# Racket: Compare elements in list recursively

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

This function is supposed to take a list (full of strings or ints, which is why it starts with that 'if' statement) and check to see if it is in ascending order.

I haven't been able to figure out how to keep it from crashing, as on the last recursive call, the 'cadr' has nothing to pull from, as the 'car' is the final element.

```
(define (my-sorted? lst)  
   (if (number? (car lst))
     (if (< (car lst) (cadr lst))
        (my-sorted? (rest lst))      
         #f)     
     #f) 
 )
```

I know that the sorted function exists, but I need to implement this function recursively.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two most basic lists that you should try are:

```
(my-sorted? '())  ; ==> #t (empty list is always sorted)
(my-sorted? '(1)) ; ==> #t (one element list is always sorted)
```

Your current code just does `car` and `cadr` on its argument so it will fail at different levels with these two tests.

The there is how to compare a number and something which is not a number. `<` expects both arguments to be numbers, but your list can be both strings and numbers. What is smaller of `"x"` and `7`? You cannot do `(< 7 "x")`.

Instead of nesting `if` you might consider `cond` which is lisps way of doing if-elseif-else. Basically you can do your code with `cond` like this:

```
(cond 
  ((not (number? (car lst))) #f)
  ((< (car lst) (cadr lst)) (my-sorted? (rest lst))
  (else #f))
```

**EDIT**

Since the list should either be all elements as string or all as number you simply can just determine the comparison function by looking at the first element and do your recursion with a named `let` and reuse the one based on the first element.

```
(define (my-sorted lst)
  ;; determine what comparison function to use, bind it to greater?
  (define greater? 
    (if (and (pair? lst) (number? (car lst)))
        >
        string>?))

  ;; main recursive loop uses that one function
  ;; this can be done with define + call as well
  (let loop ((lst lst))
    (cond ((or (null? lst) (null? (cdr lst))) ...)
          ((greater? (car lst) (cadr lst)) ...)
          (else (loop ...)))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Actually, the list can only be strings OR integers -
 sorry if I wasn't clear on that. Another condition I need to satisfy is that if the list does indeed contain both strings and ints, then I need to output an error. So, my idea was to break out the function to either handle the ints (using the if (number?) line), and then have the else condition handle the string case. I'm trying to find out if I am able to get the ASCII value of a string in racket now to make the comparison for the string case. Would a cond be able to handle all of the cases?

Comment: @BrianJay Since you have elements of the same type you can determine the comparison function once. See my edit.